# Devices not getting sync up on policy change

Tags: android-management-api

Devices enrolled to the policy are not getting updated on device patch(changing policy) or doing any change on applied policy(like disable the status bar, disable camera). The device needs a manual reboot several times to pickup up a real-time state from google and sync. Can you please advise on the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal, reproducible and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, this is an known issue and is being investigated by the Engineers at Google.
Until it is fixed you can manually sync the changes by opening the Android Device Policy app on the device and syncing it to get the latest policy changes.

Comment: That's right we're still actively looking into this issue. We haven't found the root cause yet.

Comment: @Sudhu Our deployed devices(in large number) are kiosk on enterprise application so we can't go and hit android device policy sync.

Comment: @Fred any alternative solution for it as we are getting largely affected by the bug, it will be a great help.

Comment: The issue should now be resolved. Can you confirm? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue about policy sync up is already fixed.

Comment: Hi @Deyzel, I am still facing the issue with device not syncing up as per policy

Comment: @Umang try to sync the policy manually inside the DPC